# How can I represent list of data in JSON format?

Tags: json, list, serialization, jackson

I am working on designing the JSON document of my data. Below is a single value (v) which contains `site-id`, `price-score` and `confidence-score` for now.

```
{
  "v" : {
    "site-id" : 0,
    "price-score" : 0.5,
    "confidence-score" : 0.2
  }
}
```

Now, I want to add categories list into the above JSON document. As I am going to have multiple categories for a single value (v) so I came up with below JSON document-

```
{
  "v" : {
    "site-id" : 0,
    "price-score" : 0.5,
    "confidence-score" : 0.2,
    "categories": [
          {
            "category-id": "123",
            "price-score": "0.5",
            "confidence-score": "0.2"
          },
          {
            "category-id": "321",
            "price-score": "0.2",
            "confidence-score": "0.4"
          }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know if it looks good in the way I have added list of categories in the above JSON document? Or is there any better way of doing the same? As I don't want to start having problems when I am working on serializing and deserializing the above JSON document.

Comment: You might want to make `categories` an object whose keys are the ID, instead of an array. That makes it easy to find a specific ID without looping. But other than that, it looks find.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you provide me an example that justifies this? It will make me understand much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend:

```
{
    "v" : {
        "site-id" : 0,
        "price-score" : 0.5,
        "confidence-score" : 0.2,
        "categories": {
            "123" : {
                "price-score": "0.5",
                "confidence-score": "0.2"
            },
            "321" : {
                "price-score": "0.2",
                "confidence-score": "0.4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can easily use:

```
json.v.categories[id]
```

to get information about a specific category, instead of having to write:

```
var the_category;
for (var i = 0; i < json.v.categories.length; i++) {
    if (json.v.categories[i]['category-id'] == id) {
        the_category = json.v.categories[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Another suggestion: use `_` rather than `-` in the keys (or camelCase if you prefer), as hyphen prevents you from using `.` notation to access elements (notice that I had to write `['category-id']` above instead of `.category-id`.